# Error: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

I found [this](https://github.com/pdichone/diary_webapp_course/tree/main/diary_webapp) project. After I added to `index.html` file the following Firebase configuration:

```
 <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js";

    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDoO8efzrDVveeXvqqrc39D3XiqfsyoKeU",
      authDomain: "diary-app-course-c6663.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "diary-app-course-c6663",
      storageBucket: "diary-app-course-c6663.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1031493909898",
      appId: "1:1031493909898:web:3cd71413645447b67c1c73"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
```

unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:33579/wuKO980VWbQ%3D/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:33579/wuKO980VWbQ=/ws
 Running with sound null safety 
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:33579/wuKO980VWbQ=/ws
Error: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the Firebase import scripts to your index.html file?
View the Web Installation documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:43973/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
at http://localhost:43973/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:90:29
at initializeApp (http://localhost:43973/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:96:29)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:43973/dart_sdk.js:38659:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:43973/dart_sdk.js:38690:7)
at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:43973/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:78:20)
at initializeApp (http://localhost:43973/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:94:59)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter team released a [cli](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/) which you now use to connect your projects to firebase

steps to follow

1. make sure you have [firebase cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli)
2. Next, install the FlutterFire CLI by running the following command:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

3. In the root of your application, run the configure command:

```
flutterfire configure
```

4. follow the prompts and a firebase options file will be generated
5. Then, provide the current platform options via the currentPlatform getter from the DefaultFirebaseOptions class:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Comment: I ran into *flutterfire configure
i Found 1 Firebase projects. Selecting project diary-app-course.
FirebaseProjectNotFoundException: Firebase project id "diary-app-course" could not be found on this Firebase account.* However,  Firebase Dashboard shows *diary-app-course and below diary-app-course-c6663*. What did I miss?